# How to access the failover priority value from an RDS DB Instance in AWS using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

as I stated above, I'm building a check that goes across all db instances in a region in RDS and checks to see if their failover priority is set to the correct value based on what they're purpose is.
So far I can't find anyway to check the failover priority value for an RDS DB Instance through boto3, the cli, or the api causing quite the headache.

If anyone knows of a way to do this it would be much obliged.

EDIT:

Thank you Mark B, for solving it.

As a follow up question, is there a way to access the failover value set for an RDS auto-scaling policy.
Ergo, when a Aurora Cluster on RDS has an autoscaling policy in effect to add another replica under the name "application-autoscaling-xxxx...", how do I access that replicas default failover priority?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you are looking for is `PromotionTier`, which is returned by several Boto3 RDS methods, including one of the values in the [describe_instances()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_instances) response, and in the `DBClusterMembers` list of the [describe_db_clusters()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_clusters) response.

> PromotionTier (integer) --
>
> A value that specifies the order in which an Aurora Replica is
> promoted to the primary instance after a failure of the existing
> primary instance.